# OnTouchEvent and scale gesture both for image on canvas at a time

Tags: android, canvas, scale, android-custom-view, touch-event

I am stuck logically as well as programmatically at a point in my project. Here is brief intro about what i am up to:

I have two images,one real one(bitmap1) and other is thin(alpha=0.4) a black layer(bitmap2) that overlays on bitmap1. Now I erase the part of black layer i want so that the image beneath will be visible. Further,i process this very visible part.Another feature is when i press undo Button, every thing gets reset. and user can start erasing again. Until this point, i have accomplished my goals. I have used custom view that extends view for this.

1. Now i have to zoom these images i.e. my custom view using pinch zoom at a particular point so that erasing can be done with perfection. I am able to zoom, but not at a point. Help me to zoom at a point.
2. My touch listener and scale detector interferes with each other and draws line i.e. erases after i release `ACTION_POINTER_UP`. How can i prevent this happening?
   [image]

```
public static class PaintView extends View {
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    Bitmap Bitmap1, Bitmap2;
    Bitmap Transparent;
    int X = -100;
    int Y = -100;
    int prevX = -100,prevY=-100;
    Canvas c2;
    public boolean isTouched = false;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    Path drawPath = new Path();

    public static ArrayList<Path> drawPathList;
    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.black);

        c2 = new Canvas();
        c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
        c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
        drawPathList = new ArrayList<>();
        paint.setAlpha(0);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.black);
        Bitmap2 = resize(Bitmap1,Bitmap2);

        c2 = new Canvas();
        c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
        c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
        drawPathList = new ArrayList<>();
        paint.setAlpha(0);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);


        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public Bitmap resize(Bitmap b1,Bitmap b2){

        int h= b1.getHeight();
        int w = b1.getWidth();
        b2= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b2,w,h,true);
        return b2;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        System.out.println("onDraw");
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
        if(Bitmap1!=null ){
            Bitmap2 = resize(Bitmap1,Bitmap2);
            canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, null);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        isTouched = true;
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if(!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()){
            if (mScaleFactor==1f){
                X = (int) event.getX();
                Y = (int) event.getY();
                prevX=X;
                prevY=Y;
            }else {
                X = (int) (event.getX()/mScaleFactor);
                Y = (int) (event.getY()/mScaleFactor);
            }

        }
      
        if(mScaleFactor==1f)
            paint.setStrokeWidth(60);
        else
            paint.setStrokeWidth((int)(60/mScaleFactor));

        switch (event.getAction() & event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()){
                    drawPath.moveTo(X, Y);
                    c2.drawPath(drawPath, paint);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    drawPath.lineTo(X, Y);
                    c2.drawPath(drawPath, paint);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    drawPath.lineTo(X, Y);
                    c2.drawPath(drawPath, paint);
                    drawPathList.add(drawPath);
                    drawPath.reset();

                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }


        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


    public void setBitmap1(Bitmap bitmap){
        this.Bitmap1 = bitmap;
    }

    public void resetCanvas(Context context){
       if(drawPathList.size()>0){


           DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
           int width = metrics.widthPixels;
           int height = metrics.heightPixels;

           Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
           c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, null);
           isTouched=false;
           invalidate();
       }

    }




    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return super.onScaleBegin(detector);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            super.onScaleEnd(detector);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Save the positions erased in a float[] array.

Comment: please have a look at a related question as well.thank you! :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203028/black-color-before-erasing-android-drawing-app